# Move the button using the Constraint Swift Programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

```
@objc func buttonRoundPlayer(){
    
    view?.addSubview(buttonRound)
    
    buttonRound.setTitle("Jump", for: .normal)
    buttonRound.addTarget(self, action: #selector(roundhandle), for: .touchUpInside)
    buttonRound.backgroundColor = .red
    buttonRound.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    buttonRound.layer.borderWidth = 1
    buttonRound.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    buttonRound.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:        view!.bottomAnchor),buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.bottomAnchor),buttonRound.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),buttonRound.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50)])
```

}

I recently managed to get help in understanding the layout for the button and make it work but I don't know how to adjust the constraint to move the button away from the edge of the bottom side of the screen.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by edge of bottom side, if you are talking about safe area layout guide, then you can use

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
                                     buttonRound.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                                     buttonRound.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50)])
```

**Couple of issues in your code,**

1. You have applied same constraint twice, which makes no logical sense to me

```
    buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.bottomAnchor),
    buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.bottomAnchor)
```

2. You force-unwrap view using `view!` am not really sure if its the ViewController's view or not, if it is ViewController's view, you need not force unwrap it as its a implicit optional in nature, so you should be able to write `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide` instead.
3. Through out the code you access view as if its optional, with statements like `view?.addSubview(buttonRound)`, `view!.bottomAnchor` because am not really sure which view it is and if you are so sure its optional I would suggest using safe unwrap with `if let`, `guard let` instead of `!`

```
if let view = view {
            view.addSubview(buttonRound)

            buttonRound.setTitle("Jump", for: .normal)
            buttonRound.addTarget(self, action: #selector(roundhandle), for: .touchUpInside)
            buttonRound.backgroundColor = .red
            buttonRound.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            buttonRound.layer.borderWidth = 1
            buttonRound.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

            buttonRound.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
                                         buttonRound.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                                         buttonRound.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50)])
        }
```

**EDIT:** As commented by OP below, he is seeing the error

> "SafeAreLayoutGude" is only available in iOS 11.0 or newer

OP must be using a deployment target less than iOS 11 and because OP hasn't responded to my question in comment I am updating the answer to support below iOS 11.0

```
        if let view = view {
            view.addSubview(buttonRound)

            buttonRound.setTitle("Jump", for: .normal)
            buttonRound.addTarget(self, action: #selector(roundhandle), for: .touchUpInside)
            buttonRound.backgroundColor = .red
            buttonRound.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            buttonRound.layer.borderWidth = 1
            buttonRound.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

            buttonRound.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([buttonRound.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                                         buttonRound.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50)])
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            else {
                buttonRound.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }
```

Not really sure what kind of app your are building/maintaining, iOS 11 seems way old to me, check if you really even need to support such old iOS version or not, change your iOS deployment target value in your project setting to avoid multiple compatibly issues like this.

Comment: @OptiCode22 : Hey did it work? are u still facing any issues

Comment: Hey I tried to add the code and all I got was that, the code available over iOS 11 and on top the code wouldn't run. The code isn't written in view controller but game scene class

Comment: @opticode22: What is your deployment target?

Comment: @opticode22 : I have updated my answer please check, also change your deployment target value to relevant value in xcode you need not support all iOS version just because you can, check what percent of your user base is below iOS 11 and decide

Comment: Hey Sandeep thank you I will update the code with the code you have provided me and update you if the issue is fixed

Comment: @OptiCode22: great :) please, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tickmark next to my answer :)